# Calculating dates (VBA/SQL)

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access

How can I have VBA and SQL calculate the EndDate?

EndDate = 26/10/2015 + 6 months

Comment: MS Access SQL; preferably VBA

Comment: Your question history reveals that you have not been doing a very good job of [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021) answers that help you. You should get into the habit of doing that.

Comment: 0/20 pretty dismal track record...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the VBA function

```
DateAdd ( "m", 6, yourDateVariable )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the VBA [dateadd function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) or do it directly in SQL:

```
SELECT YourDate, DateAdd("m",6,YourDate) AS YourDatePlusSixMonths FROM YourTable;
```

Or in VBA:

```vb
Dim today As Date
Dim todayPlusSix As Date
today = Date
todayPlusSix = DateAdd("m", 6, today)
Debug.Print today, todayPlusSix

'2015-03-06    2015-09-06
```